# Which STI name plate is this?

Tags: shimano, shifter

The spec sheet on my bike says I have Dura-Ace 9000 components.  I want to buy a replacement name plate.  The one on the left is genuine Shimano Y63X98020 and the one on the right is what I'm trying to get replaced.

More photos of the to-be-replaced part below:

[image: Photo comparing two Dura-Ace STI name plates]
[image: Photo comparing two Dura-Ace STI name plates]

---

Original item photos

[image: Original]
[image: Original]
[image: Original]
[image: Original]

Comment: Have you got the exact model number of your brifter?  ST-9000  or ST-9001  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/gear-spares/shimano-duraace-st9000-name-plate-fixing-screws-right-hand-y63x98020/  says that `Y63X98020` is a name plate  for the right hand lever of a ST-9000 brifter.

A review on that link says:

> unfortunately I mistakenly ordered st9000 I returned for credit and ordered the correct st9001 very happy

So from that I conclude you have ST-9001 brifters, which are 30% "thinner" and therefore a subtly different shape in the hood/body.

Some googling about suggests the part number you need for a ST-9001 is `Y00G98020` but take this with caution, I'm certainly no expert.

Photo of the suggested part number - looks about right, but hard to know for sure.

[image: From https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/gear-spares/shimano-duraace-st9001-name-plate-fixing-screws-right-hand-y00g98020/]

Fortunately its only a $12/£12/€15 item, but then it is also a single piece of plastic.